# Firebase function works in simulator but not in browser

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

this is the functions in firebase :

```
 exports.getProducts = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
            const url = `https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx`;
            const options = {
                uri: url,
                headers: { 'User-Agent': 'test' },
                transform: (body) => cheerio.load(body)
            }
            rp(options)
                .then(($) => {
                  const listings = $('.cards').first().find(".link");
                  var message = [];
                  for (var k=0;k<listings.length;k++)
                    message.push({"title":$(listings[k]).attr('title'),"url":$(listings[k]).attr('href')});
                  console.log(message)// ******** prints the right result
                  return message;   //*** how to return it ? and where ?

                  })
                  .catch((err) => response.status(400).send(err))
        });
```

when i use the `shell` it prints what it needs to print.

When I access the function `URL` ,  nothing happens.

1. I guess i am not returning the data - **how would i return this message** ?
2. How would i send a `string` parameter to it - and *access* it inside this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to explicitly send a response to the client.  Just returning it from a callback is not enough.  You will need something like this:

```
response.json(message);
```

I suggest reading over the [documentation for HTTP triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) to see some examples of how they are supposed to work.

Comment: thanks a lot! read the docs, but they are not very informative regarding http triggers and parameters. Also , if i do response.json(message) , do i need to also keep the 'return message'  ? why is the return there ?

Comment: You don't need a return statement here.   The callback from rp doesn't need to return anything.